# Python inherit abc.ABC and typing.SupportsBytes at the same time

Tags: python, abc, python-typing

I am new to writing typed Python code, but I have experience with OOP from other languages. I want to create an abstract class, that also can be serialized using `bytes` function. I correctly implement `__bytes__` method, but I would like to explicitly declare this method is available.

My class declaration look like this:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import SupportsBytes

class cls(ABC, SupportsBytes):
```

Python complains with `TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases`.

Is there any way I can alter my declaration to make it work without dropping either `abc.ABC` or `typing.SupportsBytes` from the ancestors?

I have tried replacing `abc.ABC` with `abc.ABCMeta` as well as calling `register` function on `cls`, but each attempt failed with its own error so far.

EDIT: I use Python 3.7.7

Comment: What Python version is this?

Comment: `typing.SupportsBytes` is already and ABC, it's metaclass inherits from `<class 'abc.ABCMeta'>`, just remove `ABC`... but I can't reproduce this... tried on 3.5 and 3.8.

Comment: It looks like this is specifically a Python 3.7 issue. That looks like the only version where the metaclass of SupportsBytes does not descend directly or indirectly from ABCMeta.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica ah, weird regression, but that would explain it

Comment: You're right, this is happens in Python 3.7.7. Edited

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica and juanpa.arrivillaga you are both right. Tested my code with both Python 3.5 and 3.8 and it works. I don't quite understand the reasoning behind Python 3.7. Fortunately I am not tied to it.
If any of you decides to post it as an answer, I more than willing to accept it.
Thanks.